# How to add space beetween a pair of consecutive letters and not add space beetween two characters that are not both letters?

Tags: python, string

For example:
The string BINGO!
should be B I N G O!

I have already tried:

```
s = "BINGO!"
print(" ".join(s[::1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use regex: `re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])', ' ', 'BINGO!')`

This basically says, "for every empty string in 'BINGO!' that both follows a letter and precedes a letter, substitute a space."

Comment: Thanks! It works so fine!

Comment: Great to hear! If it solved your problem, would you please accept the answer using the checkmark icon?

Answer (score 0):

I like what esramish had said, however that is a bit overcomplicated for your goal. It is as easy as this:

```
string = "BINGO"

print(" ".join(string))
```

This returns your desired output.

Comment: I hope that this helps you. Again, esramish isn't wrong, just overcoplicated. Have a nice day!

Comment: I think the issue is that Weverton doesn't want space between two characters that aren't both letters...otherwise this would work!

Comment: Ah, that's my bad! Should've read the title with more detail, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single lookahead to assert a char a-z to the right and make the pattern case insensitive.

In the replacement use the full match and a space using `\g<0>`

```
(?i)[A-Z](?=[A-Z])
```

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
- `[A-Z]` Match a single char A-Z
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char A-Z to the right of the current position

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0oTZ5/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/I2EQBe).

Example

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'(?i)[A-Z](?=[A-Z])', '\g<0> ', 'BINGO!'))
```

Output

```
B I N G O!
```

Comment: thanks! nice solution!